# How to find the value of $ \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^4}{n^4}$?

Tags: calculus

$ \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^4}{n^4}=$ ?

I found it difficult to tranform it into the integral form by the definition of Riemann sum, which is a way to solve similar problems.

Comment: No surprise, the sum diverges. (For all $k>n/2$, the terms exceed $1/16$ ad the sum is larger than $n/16$.)

Comment: HINT: Consider $$\lim_n n \cdot \frac{1}{n} \sum_k \frac{k^4}{n^4} = \lim_n n \int_0^1 x^4 dx$$

Comment: Confirmed, a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^4}{n^4}=\frac1{n^4}\sum_{k=1}^n k^4$$
and you can use *Faulhaber's formula* to get the value of
$S_4(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n k^4$ in function of $$S_3(n)=\dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2}4,\quad S_2(n)=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6,\quad S_1(n)=\dfrac{n(n+1)}2.$$
You obtain a polynomial function of degree $5$, with highest degree term $\;\dfrac{n^5}5$, hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^4}{n^4}\sim_\infty\frac{n^5}{5n^4}=\frac n5\to +\infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a typo.

By the Riemannian summation,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^p}{n^p}=\int_0^1 x^pdx=\frac1{p+1}.$$